# Org Babel Shell Command

Tags: org-babel, shell

I'm trying to set the shell command for org-babel with this:

```
(setq org-babel-sh-command "/home/luser/bash-redir-stderr.sh")
```

, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

My blocks are named "shell" and not "sh", though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org-babel-sh-command` was removed in Org 8.3, `shell-file-name` should be used instead.

Note that if you set it globally, all inferior shells will use `shell-file-name`. It might be advisable to set it as a local variable.